# Sometimes I get errors when calling GO in Scripts in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

When I follow this alter function with a `GO`, I get a syntax error near the `GO`. Without the `GO`, it runs correctly.

I want to add those `GO` because I'm writing an script altering 50 functions (alter function needs to be the first instruction of a batch). The vast majority run correctly, but four of them raise the error on their GO line, like in this example.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.f_cost_standar
    (@article varchar(24), 
     @dataCost Datetime) 
RETURNS decimal(18,5)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @resultat decimal(18,5)

    SET @resultat = NULL

    SELECT TOP 1 @resultat = preu 
    FROM costos_Standar 
    WHERE article = @article 
      AND @dataCost BETWEEN dataInici AND ISNULL(dataFinal, '31/12/2099')
    ORDER BY dataInici DESC

    RETURN @resultat
END;
GO
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure f_cost_standar, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'GO'.

When does the go fail, and what can I do to fix it?

**Update:** Thanks to @JeroenMostert I've seen that the problem was a broken newline before the GO. Now it works nicely.

Comment: `GO` is *not* a T-SQL operator, it's a batch separator interpreted by applications like SSMS, ADS, and sqlcmd. Seems you are trying to use it in applications you shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, but I'm running the script in Management Studio (hence the tag, and I also quoted in the first paragraph).

Comment: Are you, perhaps, trying to execute the above using `sys.sp_executesql`? Can yiou provide a [mre]?

Comment: Any chance there are invisible characters on the line containing `GO`, or mixed newlines either on the line of the `GO` or before it (not CR/LF throughout)? SSMS has to recognize the `GO` to strip it out and start a new batch.

Comment: Please check the settings `Tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> SQL Server -> General -> Batch Separator field` and make sure, it says `GO`

Comment: Side note, a clause like `@dataCost between dataInici and ISNULL(dataFinal,'31/12/2099')` won't be SARGable. Use Date boundaries and handle your `NULL` values properly: `dataInici <= @dataCost AND (dataFinal >= @dataCost OR dataFinal IS NULL)` Also, multi-line scalar functions can perform very poorly. As you're running 2017 there is no option for inlining, so I would suggest that you switch to using an inline table value function too.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I believe you are right. I have generated the script automatically from sys.sql_modules.definition and it may probably have those mixed newlines.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, you were right. I have replaced the newlines before the failing GOes with full CR/LF and now the script works nicely. If you post your comment as an answer, I will approve it. Thank you.

Comment: Scalar functions are notoriously poor performers and you say you have more than 50 of them. Functions like the one above could easily be converted to an inline table valued function and the performance and flexibility would be greatly improved.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange, I will propose it to the project director.